# How do you include WHERE clause in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

The below calculates the difference between 2 dates for the entire date range within the table.

Sample Data:

```
Name    Date1        Date2
A       2020/07/27   2020/07/27
B       2020/07/27   2020/07/27
```

So far attempt with this below code-

```
AGE = DATEDIFF(CALENDAR[DATE1],CALENDAR[DATE2],DAY)
```

How would I limit DATE2 to:

a. >= 2020/07/27
b. Between 2020/04/01 and 2020/07/26 inclusive
c. Last month
d. This month

I would like to plot these on a bar chart to show the average for each one - would I have to create a measure for each one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need one measure with your expected calculation. Bar chart will automatically distinguish everything itself. If you provide some sample data with your expected output, it will be easier to understand for all and give you appropriate solution.

Comment: Hello, There's not really anything to share, it's just a table with Name, Date1 and Date2. I have changed to import mode now so it's easier and have created a calculated column to work out the difference between Date1 and Date2. So I can create a measure to calculate the average for each date range and then plot them on one bar chart. I`m not sure how you'd do it with only one measure though?

Comment: There are lot more to show yet. Put your sample input data here in tabular format. Add 6/7 sample row of data. And finally add your expected output (may be an image of your expected bar chart). Note: Check my sample table I have added in your question. You can now eidt data there.

Answer (score 0):

```
AGE = Calculate(
DATEDIFF(CALENDAR[DATE1],CALENDAR[DATE2],DAY), 
Filter(Calendar,CALENDAR[DATE2]>= 2020/07/27))
```

In a similar way you can use the **Filter** expression for case b and c.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu. It says a single value for the date cannot be determined. It works ok without the filter but not when I specify a date range. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share sample data and screenshot of error ?

Comment: This is the error
"A single value for column 'DATE1' in table 'CALENDAR' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."
 I'm not sure how I'd share the data since it's in Power BI but the table contains many rows and for each row I am trying to calculate the difference between Date1 and Date2, and then get the average of that. Like I say, it works no problem without specifying a date range.